# Pass a raw function pointer where the JNA definition expects a Callback?

Tags: java, winapi, callback, jna

I'm working with a JNA interface that expects a [`Callback`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/com/sun/jna/Callback.html). I have the raw address of a native function `g`, which is the function I want to install as a callback. I am calling native function `f`, which expects a callback, and I would like JNA to marshall my raw pointer to `g` as the callback by just passing the address of `g` through to `f`. Is this possible with JNA?

**ILLUSTRATION**

Here's a concrete illustration of what I mean. I'm working with Win32 and I want to register a window class whose default window procedure is `DefWindowProc`. In the ordinary course I would do the following in C to register a window class having the default window procedure:

```
WNDCLASSEX wcex;
ZeroMemory(&wcex, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));
wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
...
wcex.lpfnWndProc = LoadLibrary("user32", "DefWindowProcA");
...
ATOM atom = RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
```

However, sometimes I want to register a window class with a different window procedure. In C, I would do exactly the above except:

```
wcex.lpfnWndProc = MyWindowProc; // Address of my custom window procedure
```

Hopefully it is now clear what the difficulty is in JNA. I am writing Java code similar to:

```
WNDCLASSEX wcex = new WNDCLASSEX.ByReference();
wcex.cbSize = WNDCLASSEX.size();
...
wcex.lpfnWndProc = new MyWindowProc(); // where MyWindowProc implements the Callback interface;
                                       // but what if I want to just set it to the address of
                                       // DefWindowProcA?
ATOM atom = User32.RegisterClassEx(wcex);
```

**CAVEAT**

I am aware that I can define two alternate versions of the function `f` in Java, one of which takes a `Callback` and one of which takes a `Pointer`, and pass my address to `g` to the `Pointer` version. I'm also aware that I can create a "wrapper callback" for DefWindowProcA. For various reasons, these are not adequate solutions.

Comment: Write an adapter. Write an implementation of Callback that calls your function pointer.

Comment: @David Please read the question all the way to the bottom. The OP has already said they don't consider the "wrapper callback" approach to be okay. Also, that was also the solution approach for the initial iteration of my answer, and the OP explicitly commented that they wanted something different.

Comment: @Chris I can read. It's just that it needs to be done the way I say. I cannot see how a raw pointer can some how be a `Callback`.

Comment: @David It doesn't "need" to be done that way, it's just the cleanest way to do it. The type-punning solution I posted is ugly, but it actually works. (I use something similar but even uglier in production code.)

Comment: @Chris I can't see how a pointer can be a `Callback`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan At a fundamental level (i.e., if you look beyond JNA), callbacks _are_ pointers. At the JNA level, of course they're not the same, since `Callback` has a `this` pointer and `Pointer` (and more specifically, `Function`) does not. However, with the marshal/unmarshal approach that my post uses, JNA creates a proxy object for the `Callback` that makes it delegate correctly.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Demonstration of callback proxy in action: http://i.stack.imgur.com/cVtoT.png

Comment: @DavidHeffernan (and the OP too): I've put together a fun little program for testing out callbacks, both Java-side ones as well as type-punned C-side ones: https://gist.github.com/cky/7397db4908fa9616539b

Comment: I've also successfully made Java 8 method references and lambdas usable as callbacks; JNA doesn't currently have direct support for Java 8's new features (especially with regard to extension methods), but with some care/workarounds you can still get things to work. (Same link as before: https://gist.github.com/cky/7397db4908fa9616539b)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to use an external pointer as a `Callback`, you type-pun the way C programmers do: with unions.

```
public static class WindowProcUnion extends Union {
    public Pointer ptr;
    public WinUser.WindowProc wndProc;

    public WindowProcUnion(Pointer ptr) {
        this.ptr = ptr;
        setType("ptr");
        write();
        setType("wndProc");
        read();
    }
}
```

You can now read the `wndProc` field and get back a usable window procedure callback.

---

For this use case, `DefWindowProc` is actually exported via the `User32` class, so you can just create a callback to invoke it directly:

```
public static class DefWindowProc implements WinUser.WindowProc {
    @Override
    public LRESULT callback(WinDef.HWND hWnd, int uMsg, WinDef.WPARAM wParam, WinDef.LPARAM lParam) {
        return User32.INSTANCE.DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Have a look at the [`Win32WindowDemo` class](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/contrib/native_window_msg/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Win32WindowDemo.java) for an example of a window procedure that delegates to `DefWindowProc`.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Jester-Young. That didn't answer my question but it did teach me some stuff I didn't know which was very helpful. I do "*really* want" to use an external pointer as a callback. It's part of the specification of the job I'm doing. However, it's not just that. I want to be able to pass *either* an instance of `Callback` *or* the raw address of a function that lives in a DLL to *the same* function, depending on what I have on hand at the moment.

Comment: I totally understand. At my work, we had a case where our third-party library expected a callback in the form of a global variable, which I had to get and set via JNA. I will try to adapt our work code to your case. I may have to do some testing first, so bear with me.

Comment: Sure thing. Like I said, I've had to do something like this for work code, so the whole subject is by no means new to me. And back then, I had to spend a _lot_ of time studying the JNA source to figure out how to get it going in the first place, so I'm only too happy to share the technique with others. :-D